# Adding a zero to my filename in batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Im trying to add 1 to the current day but for that to be possible i have get the date to single digit(because it cant add 01 to 1 or something like that). After that works, i cant get it back to double digit (ex: 01, 02, 09) 
My code looks like this:

```
Set /a day=%date:~1,2% (this is 2)
Set /a day+=1            (this is 3 now)
Set day=0%day%       (this is zero)
```

This only says the 0 in front
I tried with two different variables but it works same

Comment: I think I have posted a date math batch file solution a dozen times on StackOverFlow. Did you search? Another option is to use Powershell which makes date calculations effortless with much less code.

Comment: Its the simplest solution i got for this problem. I searched how to make sentences with variables for adding the zero, the code seems as it should work but doesnt

Comment: What happens when you add one to February 28?

Comment: Those are the times i manually do it

Comment: @MarianDiam By the way: The wrong result of your three lines is caused by embedding them in a command block starting with `(` and ending with matching `)` with `Day` defined/modified inside the command block and don't use [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html). Questions caused by not knowing about how Windows command processor preprocesses environment variable references before execution of a command line or an entire command block and how to use delayed environment variable expansion are asked daily on Stack Overflow. Run `set /?` and read all help pages.

Comment: The command line `set /A day=%date:~1,2%` is to remove the leading space, right? why not using `set /A day=%date: =%`, so two-digit numbers are also handled correctly? By the way, I bet your code fragment is placed within a parenthesised block of code, so `day` becomes expanded to the value it has got when the whole block is parsed, because you lack using [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)...

Comment: How to calculate tomorrows date was posted several times on Stack Overflow as Squashman wrote. Two examples can be seen on [Windows batch event reminder for next day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37532952/).

Answer (score 1):

By changing the number in this variable `day=+1` to will add more days to your result, or changing to `day=-1` will remove a day etc..

```
@echo off
set day=+1
echo>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%day%,now) : d=weekday(s)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^& right(100+month(s),2)^& right(100+day(s),2)
for /f %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set "result=%%a"
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
set "YYYY=%result:~0,4%"
set "MM=%result:~4,2%"
set "DD=%result:~6,2%"
set "result=%yyyy%-%mm%-%dd%"
echo %DD%
pause
```

This will only echo the day +1. If however you want to echo the full date result, simply do `echo %result%`

`YYYY`, `MM` and `DD` have been split into single variables anyway so you can use it if you like.

Just as a sidenote:

```
echo>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%day%,now) : d=weekday(s)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^& right(100+month(s),2)^& right
```

is pretty much the same as:

```
echo s=DateAdd("d",%day%,now) : d=weekday(s) >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" 
echo WScript.Echo year(s)^& right(100+month(s),2)^& right >>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
```

`CMD` will pretty much do the same for both and that is to pipe the output to file. I simply do this so by reading the line, you can immediately see what the line does, `echo`ing to external file, the string that follows.

Answer (score 1):

As @Squashman suggested, PowerShell makes this pretty easy.

```
FOR /F %a IN ('powershell -NoProfile -Command "'{0:yyyy-MM-dd}' -f (Get-Date).AddDays(1)"') DO SET "NEWDATE=%a"
ECHO %NEWDATE%
```

In a .bat script, double the variable **%** characters.

```
FOR /F %%a IN ('powershell -NoProfile -Command "'{0:yyyy-MM-dd}' -f (Get-Date).AddDays(1)"') DO SET "NEWDATE=%%a"
ECHO %NEWDATE%
```

It is even easier if you use PowerShell and not cmd where it must be wrapped in a FOR loop.

```
$newdate = '{0:yyyy-MM-dd}' -f (Get-Date).AddDays(1)
```

Comment: Im not too good with cmd and worse with powetshell but your code solution sure works!

Comment: The "loop" runs over each output line from the command. This command only outputs one (1) line. The first field from the line, `%%a`, is placed into the NEWDATE variable. This works as designed by Microsoft.