# I want to retrieve data of particular date If user provide? Otherwise, it retrieves T-1 date which is currently fetching. Through Batch file

Tags: batch-file, sqlcmd

I have created a batch file which retrieves `T-1` data from the database. But I want to retrieve data of backdated data of date which user enter through cmd.

Can you please help me on this?

I want to retrieve data of particular date If user provide? Otherwise, it retrieves T-1 date which is currently fetching:

```
set qty=-1

:loop4weekends

set "separator1=-"
set "separator2=_"

echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%qty%,now)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" d=weekday(s)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^&_
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs"         right(100+month(s),2)^&_
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs"         right(100+day(s),2)^&_
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs"         d
for /f %%a in ('cscript //nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set result=%%a
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"

endlocal& set "YY=%result:~0,4%" & set "MM=%result:~4,2%" & set "DD=%result:~6,2%" & set "daynum=%result:~-1%"

:: if the daynum is a weekend then loop to get the friday
set "weekend="

if %daynum% EQU 1 set weekend=1&set "qty=-3"
if %daynum% EQU 7 set weekend=1&set "qty=-2"
if defined weekend goto :loop4weekends

set "day=%YY%%separator1%%MM%%separator1%%DD%"
set "day1=%YY%%separator2%%MM%%separator2%%DD%"

sqlcmd  -U %SQLServerUserName% -P %SQLServerPassword% -S %MachineIP% -Q "exec P_SP @companyFundIDs=N'',@inputDate=N''"  -d %ClientDB% -o "Fil_Trade_%day1%.csv" -s"," -W

ECHO CSV file has been generated successfully
pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an default value, unless the user enters something different. That's quite easy, because `set /p` leaves the variable unchanged, when user just presses ENTER. So just define a default value before asking the user:

```
set "result=defaultValue"
set /p "result=Enter date ([ENTER] for default "%result%"): "
echo %result%
```

You should add a bit of code to verify, if the string the user entered is a valid date. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37552535/2152082) is an example.